# Rails - Tool to generate migrations from class diagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched and found some tools to create the diagram class for models of a existing rails application. But what about the reverse? Is there anyway that I can draw the diagram class of my application and it generates the migrations? Thanks!

Comment: Drawing a class diagram from the schema is pretty easy since you can dump the schema to SQL and use SQL visualisation tools. Doing the inverse is a lot more complex since you would need to convert to the ActiveRecord migration DSL. Frankly it would not be that useful anyways since you should be creating models and migrations as part of TDD/BDD cycle.

Comment: I agree, but I'm startint a project right now, and I'm modeling it with UML... would be nice to have a tool that automatically generates the model logic for starting